# Fraction calculator in python workaround

Tags: python

So, I have to create a python script that given 2 fractions and an operand will print the result of the operation. This was intended to be solved by firstly asking for one fraction and saving it into a variable, then ask for another fraction and lastly ask for the operand. But out of curiosity I've tried to give this problem a different point of view.
My idea was to ask for the full operation and save the input string into a variable, then with the function exec() I could get the decimal result of the given operation, finally to deal with decimals my idea was to multiply by 10 to the power of the number of decimal digits and then dividing by 10 to that same power, this way I could have a fraction as a result. So I went on to code and managed to program this out, my only issue is that the number of decimal digits is limited so normally the result that my script returns is a very big fraction that is very close to what the real fraction is. So I was wondering if there is any workaround for this. Here is my code and an example for further explanation:

```
op = input('Enter operation: ')
try:
    exec('a = ' + op)
except:
    print('Invalid operation')
def euclides(a, b):
    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        if a < b: b = b%a
        else: a = a%b
    if a == 0: return b
    elif b == 0: return a
print(f'{int(a*10**len(str(a).split(".")[1])/euclides(a*10**len(str(a).split(".")[1]),10**len(str(a).split(".")[1])))}/{int(10**len(str(a).split(".")[1])/euclides(a*10**len(str(a).split(".")[1]),10**len(str(a).split(".")[1])))}')
```

EXAMPLE:

1. op input => 4/3+5/7
2. Result of script => 5119047619047619/2500000000000000 = 2.04761904761
3. Result I'm looking for => 43/21 = 2.047619 period

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `round`? Or the `decimal` module?

Comment: This script seems unnecessarily complicated...

Comment: Please split the last line up into multiple lines. I currently have no idea what it even does. Also, do `a = eval(op)` instead of the exec.

Comment: Agreed with @Seth, having a huge line like that at the bottom is going to make the code unreadable an un-maintainable. It's good to break up code like that into as many lines as possible, and give everything meaningful names.

Comment: Completely agree with both of you guys @Random Davis but it is expected of me to give a working program in as few lines as possible

Comment: "in as few lines as possible" shouldn't mean that packing a bunch of stuff on one line is seen as an improvement.  Readability is a critical part of any program, and sacrificing it to eliminate a few lines on your screen or even a few total characters in your script is just plain wrong.  If you have an instructor that is giving points for doing this, then that instructor is misguiding you.

Comment: Sadly I don't make the rules I just follow them, I agree with you but unfortunately nothing is going to change @Steve

Comment: I'll look into the decimal module @Random Davis

Comment: @JorgeJuan it's fine if your [mre] contains more lines than your final code; we'd prefer something more readable than something that condensed and impossible to read. "As few lines as possible" in the case of a MRE means something more like "as little code as possible", or in other words, there shouldn't be any unrelated code.

Comment: I'll work on a more readable version and bring it back here

Comment: @JorgeJuan - I've been in this situation before where a student may have misunderstood what the instructor wants.  I'd suggest that you construct your code in a way that makes the most sense to you.  Then, at the end, you can compact everything onto one line once the code does what you want.  Even then, I'd suggest that you submit both the original and compressed versions to your instructor to make sure that you know which one is preferred.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if your instructor preferred the more robust and understandable version, despite what you think is being asked of you.

Comment: That's sound advice @Steve I'll make sure I do that when submitting my work

Comment: I just came back and really looked at your problem.  If you want to come up with `43/21`, which it seems is what you're saying, you're not going to get there with your current algorithm. You lose the exact rational representation in the very first operation in your program, where you reduce your rational expression to the single float `a`.  I don't know if there's a way to transform that to `43/21`, but your current approach isn't going to do that.

Comment: Do you have a problem statement from your instructor that you can share?  BTW, if it happens that you could use the `fractions` Python module, you'd be able to solve this task very easily. I assume you can't do that.

Comment: I do have a statement but it's in Spanish, I think he won't have a problem in me using the module and looking into it it seems like the solution I needed. Anyways I'll submit 2 different drafts of the exercise, one done the traditional way and one with the fraction module so he'll have no problem, you really helped me out, thanks! @Steve

Comment: Just tried out the fraction module works wonders! @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your constraints as to what standard or add-on modules you can use?  Without taking into account constraints you haven't specified, there are much better ways to go about what you're doing.  Your problem seems to be summed up by "the result that my script returns is a very big fraction" and your question seems to be "I was wondering if there is any workaround for this?".  There are a number of "work arounds".  But it's pretty hard to guess what the best solution is for you as you don't tell us what tools you can and can't use to accomplish your task.

As an example, here's an elegant solution if you can use regular expressions and the `fractions` module, and if you can assume that the input will always be in the very strict format of `<int>/<int>+<int>/<int>`:

```
import re
import fractions

op = input('Enter operation: ')

m = re.match(r"(\d+)/(\d+)\+(\d+)/(\d+)", op)
if not m:
    raise('Invalid operation')
gps = list(map(int, m.groups()))

f =  fractions.Fraction(gps[0], gps[1]) + fractions.Fraction(gps[2], gps[3])

print(f)
print (float(f))
print(round(float(f), 6))
```

Result:

```
43/21
2.0476190476190474
2.047619
```

This answers your current question.  I don't, however, know if this violates the terms of your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Could just turn all natural numbers into `Fraction`s and evaluate:

```
>>> op = '4/3+5/7'
>>> import re, fractions
>>> print(eval(re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'fractions.Fraction(\1)', op)))
43/21
```

Works for other cases as well (unlike the accepted answer's solution, which only does the *sum* of exactly *two* fractions that must be *positive* and must not have spaces), for example:

```
>>> op = '-1/2 + 3/4 - 5/6'
>>> print(eval(re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'fractions.Fraction(\1)', op)))
-7/12
```

Checking:

```
>>> -7/12, -1/2 + 3/4 - 5/6
(-0.5833333333333334, -0.5833333333333334)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# fraction calculator

num1 = input("Enter first fraction: ")
num2 = input("Enter second fraction: ")
operation = int(input("Addition - 1 or Subtraction - 2 or Multiplication = 3 or Division = 4: "))

def separate(x):
    List = []
    List2 = []
    reach = False
    for i in x:
        if i == "/":
            reach = True
        if reach and i != "/":
            List2.append(i)
        if not reach:
            List.append(i)
    nume = int("".join(List))
    deno = int("".join(List2))
    return nume,deno

def lowest(nume,deno):
    numMax = max(nume,deno)
    cf = None
    for i in range(numMax,1,-1):
        if nume%i == 0 and deno%i==0:
            cf = i
            break
    if cf == None:
        lowestNume = nume
        lowestDeno = deno
    else:
        lowestNume = nume/cf
        lowestDeno = deno/cf
    return lowestNume,lowestDeno
    
def calc(x,y,z):
    nume1,deno1 = separate(x)
    nume2,deno2 = separate(y)
    
    if z!=4:
        newDeno = deno1*deno2
    
    if z==1:
        newNume = (nume1*deno2)+(nume2*deno1)
    elif z==2:
        newNume = (nume1*deno2)-(nume2*deno1)
    elif z==3:
        newNume = nume1*nume2
    elif z==4:
        newNume = nume1*deno2
        newDeno = deno1*nume2
    
    finalNume,finalDeno = lowest(newNume,newDeno)
    return int(finalNume),int(finalDeno)


nume,deno = calc(num1,num2,operation)
print(nume,"/",deno)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).